# Wordpress: execute JQuery on ajax generated div

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am implementing some kind of Questionary plugin in Wordpress, thus, i generate some content using Ajax.

In one of the questions, the user is asked about the time.

Having a custom javascript and css for my timepicker, to achieve the visualization, i only need to define the div like following:

```
<div id="picker"></div>
```

and then, in my correctly enqueued javascript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#picker').dateTimePicker();

}
```

At this point, it works for templates and hardcoded pages.

However, if i generate this div dynamically, then the javascript `dateTimePicker();` is not getting called again, and thus my div does not receive any content.

Is there any way to have the function being called on all generated objects too?

***Edit***

Louys Patrice Bessette proposed to use success callback of my ajax request.

I tried using the `success` field of my ajax request of my questionnaire - continue button. So I have this javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('body').on('click', '#tra_continue', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var req_data = {
        action: 'fetch_question',
        report_id: $('input#report_id').val(),
        answers: '',
        success: function(response){
            $('#picker').dateTimePicker();
          } 
    };    

    // try to animate
    $contentBox.animate({opacity: 0.5}, 100);

    jQuery.get(tra_object.ajaxurl, req_data, function (response) {
        console.log("AJAX RESPONSE: "+response);
        $contentBox
                .html(response)
                .animate({opacity: 1}, 100);
    });
});
```

So this i tried actually inserting the initialization both in success field of ajax request and in the jQuery.get callback function, but nothing seems to work... :(

Comment: Does the `<div id="picker"></div>` exist? I don't see where you append it. And make sure you instantiate the plugin only once... The code above will do on each `#tra_continue` click...

Comment: The `<div id="picker"></div>` is contained in the ajax response. The `#tra_continue` button is also always generated in the ajax response.

Comment: You misplaced the success callback! See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ready` event occurs only when the page has fully loaded.

So you have to instanciate datepicker in the Ajax success callback, right after the addition of `<div id="picker"></div>` element to the DOM. Something like:

```
success: function(response){
  $('some-selector').append('<div id="picker"></div>');
  $('#picker').dateTimePicker();
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You misplaced the success callback!

I taught you were using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), but you are using [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)... Which is a "shorthand" method.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('body').on('click', '#tra_continue', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // That is the data you SEND!
    var req_data = {
      action: 'fetch_question',
      report_id: $('input#report_id').val(),
      answers: '',
    };

    // try to animate
    $contentBox.animate({opacity: 0.5}, 100);

    jQuery.get(tra_object.ajaxurl, req_data, function (response) {  // That function is the "success" callback!
      console.log("AJAX RESPONSE: "+response);
      $contentBox
        .html(response)  // That is inserting the response (additional HTML markup) to DOM.
        .animate({opacity: 1}, 100);

        $('#picker').dateTimePicker();  // Instantiate the datepicker plugin HERE.
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hey, this seems not to work for me somehow... I edited the topic

Comment: Be sure the library is loaded and do not use the same `id` more than once.

Comment: Could it be a problem, that I use the id field on a dynamically generated tags?

Comment: No. There is no problem about the id, if it remains **unique** on that page.

Comment: thank you, it did work... One question, if a have a lot of different button types, not just the "Continue" button, what would be the best way to instantiate the datepicker?